# Is there a way to use a Bridge as an Exit Node?

Tags: configuration, bridge

I know a bridge is used an an entry node, but what if I want to use either another Bridge as an Exit Node, or at least, use the Bridge function for the Exit Node rather than the entry node.

**CLARIFICATION:**

I want set an external Bridge as my Exit Node, not act as a Bridge myself.

Answer (score 1):

if it's configured like one - yes. A bridge is just an "entrance" for a Tor network, and it's normal if you're *also* allowing exiting traffic from one. So you can't use **remote** bridge as an exit if it's not configured as one, and you **can** configure *your* bridge to be also an exit node. That's it =)

UPDATE: by @Anonymous request for information :

To make a Bridge you **must** add to your `torrc` next lines :

```
BridgeRelay 1
PublishServerDescriptor 1
```

or - if you want to be a *stealth bridge* second one must be zero( i.e. `PublishServerDescriptor 0` )

Pluggable transports, etc are **irrelevant** - they're configured separatedly *if there's a need to do so*. Basically theese two lines **are** making you a bridge.

To become an exit you **must** add just *one* line :

```
ExitRelay 1
```

and that's it! Configure your `ExitPolicy` set to reflect what you're *explicitly* allow and deny, but even the [default ones](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) are good for a start :

```
reject *:25
reject *:119
reject *:135-139
reject *:445
reject *:563
reject *:1214
reject *:4661-4666
reject *:6346-6429
reject *:6699
reject *:6881-6999
accept *:*
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps of doing that in torrc?

Comment: @Anonymous take a look at my update, feel free to request an additional details if you need them

Comment: Thank you. But I see these are to make me a Bridge, rather I'm a user who wants to set a bridge to be my Exit Node, not act as an Exit Node myself.

Comment: @Anonymous you will be able to do what you want if it's configured to be a bridge and an exit node. You can use `StrictNodes` and `ExitNodes` config clauses and *try* to set your bridge as an exit. You will succeed if it's configured as an exit too, but if it don't - then you will fail.

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore this further. I've been trying to set bridges as Exit Nodes using `ExitNodes` and `StrictNodes` for hours now. Doesn't seem to work. Though when I get a connection and be able to browse, some sites can still see that I'm using Tor. Though I'm not sure if Tor is even correctly routing Exit traffic through that Exit Bridge.